# html2haml resolves to 2.0.0 when latest version is 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, haml, html2haml

I'm trying to `bundle update nokogiri` with `gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.1'`

and Bundler gave me an error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    nokogiri (>= 1.7.1, ~> 1.7)

    anemone was resolved to 0.7.2, which depends on
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.0)

    haml-rails was resolved to 0.9.0, which depends on
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)

    quickbooks-ruby (~> 0.4.2) was resolved to 0.4.6, which depends on
      nokogiri
```

`haml-rails` 0.9.0 is the latest version.. and I expected `html2haml` to resolve to 2.1.0 as well but it did not...

Could someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: * update

I ran `bundle update html2haml` without specifying it in gemfile

Comment: ** update

Because updating all gems seemed to get me the correct version of nokogiri,
I ran `bundle update` and took a note of gems that have been updated, and carefully ran update on each one that seems to be associated with `haml`

For me, I had to `bundle update` haml_lint, html2haml, roadie, then nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

try requiring `html2haml, '~> 2.1'` in your gemfile. Seems like the requirements aren't smart enough to force it to upgrade from the cached version you have installed locally.